# trying to simplify a function by making it dynamic depending on the variable being be passed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not sure how to word what I am trying to do, but if you look at my code you will see very quickly. I believe I am close to accomplishing what I am trying to do but I am missing some small pieces. If anyone could help I would be greatly appreciative.
Basically, I am trying to shorten up my code and make it more dynamic.

The problem is that `healthSign` doesn't get the class correctly.  When I look at the inspector, this is what is outputting `<div class="signImage ' + healthValue">` when it should be `<div class="signImage good">`.

I believe the mix up is that I am trying to pass a variable as a string and as a object and that I am not using the correct punctuation or syntax.

Here is my jquery:

```
$("#click").click(function () {
    var func = $("#run").val(),
        signP = $('.signImage').find('p'),
        bodyConditionP = $('#bodyCondition').find('p'),
        reproductionP = $('#reproduction').find('p'),
        weaningWeightsP = $('#weaningWeights').find('p'),
        healthSign = $('.signImage');
    signP.empty();
    bodyConditionP.empty();
    reproductionP.empty();
    weaningWeightsP.empty();
    console.log(func);

    function blah(healthValue) {
        signP.append(healthValue.sign);
        healthSign.attr('class', 'signImage');
        alert(healthValue);
        healthSign.addClass("' + healthValue + '");
        signP.append(healthValue.sign);
        bodyConditionP.append(healthValue.bodyCondition);
        reproductionP.append(healthValue.reproduction);
        weaningWeightsP.append(healthValue.weaningWeights);
    }
    if (func === 'good') {
        blah(good);
    }
    else if (func === 'moderate') {
        blah(moderate);
    }
    else if (func === 'poor') {
        blah(poor);
    }
});
```

This was the longer version of my script:

```
$("#click").click(function () {
    var func = $("#run").val(),
        signP = $('.signImage').find('p'),
        bodyConditionP = $('#bodyCondition').find('p'),
        reproductionP = $('#reproduction').find('p'),
        weaningWeightsP = $('#weaningWeights').find('p'),
        healthSign = $('.signImage');
    signP.empty();
    bodyConditionP.empty();
    reproductionP.empty();
    weaningWeightsP.empty();
    console.log(func);
    if (func === 'good') {
        console.log('good');
        signP.append(good.sign);
        healthSign.attr('class', 'signImage');
        healthSign.addClass('good');
        signP.append(good.sign);
        bodyConditionP.append(good.bodyCondition);
        reproductionP.append(good.reproduction);
        weaningWeightsP.append(good.weaningWeights);
    }
    else if (func === 'moderate') {
        console.log('moderate');
        signP.append(moderate.sign);
        signP.append(good.sign);
        healthSign.attr('class', 'signImage');
        healthSign.addClass('moderate');
        signP.append(moderate.sign);
        bodyConditionP.append(moderate.bodyCondition);
        reproductionP.append(moderate.reproduction);
        weaningWeightsP.append(moderate.weaningWeights);
    }
    else if (func === 'poor') {
        console.log('poor');
        signP.append(poor.sign);
        healthSign.attr('class', 'signImage');
        healthSign.addClass('poor');
        signP.append(poor.sign);
        bodyConditionP.append(poor.bodyCondition);
        reproductionP.append(poor.reproduction);
        weaningWeightsP.append(poor.weaningWeights);
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you have an error?  What is it currently doing and what is it supposed to be doing?

Comment: No error, it passes the object information but does not add the new class. it adds the class as an object which obviousley doesnt work

Comment: i believe that healthSign.addClass("' + healthValue + '"); is where the problem is.

Comment: when i look at the inspector, this is what is outputting <div class="signImage ' + healthValue"> when it should be <div class="signImage good">

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#click").click(function () {
  var func = $("#run").val(),
    signP = $('.signImage').find('p'),
    bodyConditionP = $('#bodyCondition').find('p'),
    reproductionP = $('#reproduction').find('p'),
    weaningWeightsP = $('#weaningWeights').find('p'),
    healthSign = $('.signImage');
 signP.empty();
 bodyConditionP.empty();
 reproductionP.empty();
 weaningWeightsP.empty();
 console.log(func);
  if (func === 'good'){
    blah(good);
  }
  else if (func === 'moderate'){
    blah(moderate);
  }
  else if (func === 'poor'){
   blah(poor);
  }
});

 function blah(healthValue){
  signP.append(healthValue.sign);
  healthSign.attr('class', 'signImage');
  alert(healthValue);
  healthSign.addClass("' + healthValue + '");  // see below for this line
  signP.append(healthValue.sign);
  bodyConditionP.append(healthValue.bodyCondition);
  reproductionP.append(healthValue.reproduction);
  weaningWeightsP.append(healthValue.weaningWeights);
}
```

for that line try

```
tempVar = healthValue.toString();
healthSign.addClass(tempVar);
```

Comment: I was almost positive your solution would work but it still adds the class as an object. this is the output when i look at the dom in the inspector <div class="signImage [object object]"> not sure why the moethod toString is having no effect.

Comment: alos when i take the function blah() out of the click event it doesnt work entirely. meaning not only does it not add the class but it wont pass any of the objects

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because `healthValue` is an object.  You need the string used to get the object, which is `func`:

```
healthSign.addClass(func);
```

---

You have some opportunities to further improve your code that you might consider.

- There's no reason to use the function `blah()`.  Instead, assign `healthValue` to a variable before that code is run.
- Store `good`, `moderate`, and `poor` as properties of an object so
  that you can access them by property name and get rid of your `if`
  statements.
- Set the class of `healthSign` in a single operation.
- Instead of `$(".someSelector").find("p")`, you can just do `$(".someSelector p")`.
- You can call `.empty()` as soon as you select your elements.  This is a personal preference thing.  It turns 8 lines of code into 4, but it's arguable that it makes the code less obvious what it's doing.
- You are appending `healthValue.sign` to `signP` twice.  Is that on purpose?  If so, that can be a single call.

```
var healthValues = {
    good: good,
    moderate: moderate,
    poor: poor
};

$("#click").click(function () {
    var func = $("#run").val(),
        signP = $('.signImage p').empty(),
        bodyConditionP = $('#bodyCondition p').empty(),
        reproductionP = $('#reproduction p').empty(),
        weaningWeightsP = $('#weaningWeights p').empty(),
        healthSign = $('.signImage'),
        healthValue = healthValues[func];

    signP.append(healthValue.sign, healthValue.sign);
    healthSign.attr('class', 'signImage ' + func);
    bodyConditionP.append(healthValue.bodyCondition);
    reproductionP.append(healthValue.reproduction);
    weaningWeightsP.append(healthValue.weaningWeights);
});
```

You don't really need all those variables.  You could shorten it up a bit more:

```
var healthValues = {
    good: good,
    moderate: moderate,
    poor: poor
};

$("#click").click(function () {
    var func = $("#run").val(),
        healthValue = healthValues[func];
    $('.signImage p').empty().append(healthValue.sign, healthValue.sign);
    $('#bodyCondition p').empty().append(healthValue.bodyCondition);
    $('#reproduction p').empty().append(healthValue.reproduction);
    $('#weaningWeights p').empty().append(healthValue.weaningWeights);
    $('.signImage').attr('class', 'signImage ' + func);
});
```